# Conditionally Saving has_many_through Relationships

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

In Rails, how would one conditionally associated records on a `has_many_through` relationship?  Using the following Rails docs example:

```
class Physician < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :patients, through: :appointments
end

class Appointment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :physician
  belongs_to :patient
end

class Patient < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :appointments
  has_many :physicians, through: :appointments
end
```

Suppose I wanted to have an appointment reference exactly two physicians. That is, there will not be any appointment record one there is less than two physicians assigned. However, how could that appointment then reference each physician?

**Example**

Basically, I want to keep track of users liking other users and mutual likes between them. A connection is established when both users like each other. But I don't want a connection when only one user likes another but it is not reciprocal.

When User A likes User B. A "like" is created.
When User B likes User A. A "like" is created. A "connection" is also created.

The connection should be able to call:
`connection.users`

The user should be able to call:
`user.likes`
`user.connections`

The problem that I'm having is how can that relationship table know when it is mutual?

Comment: Can you share something example ?

Comment: I added more explanation.

Comment: @user3162553 A particular `user` can have many `like`s, but can a particular `like` have many `user`s? It seems like the relationship you are trying to make is not many to many.

Comment: The problem is I'm not sure how to set up the relationship. I'm not sure when to create a connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the original question, a `connection` doesnt make a difference between the two users, so i would model it as a `one to many` relationship and validate it only has two users.

A like has two users, the `liker` (giver of the like) and the `likee` (receiver of the like). Every time you create new `like`, you should check if the `likee` also likes the `liker`. `If likee.likes.where(likee: liker)?` If yes, then create the new connection with both users.

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :likes
    has_many :connections
end

class Like < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => 'liker_id'
    belongs_to :user, :foreign_key => 'likee_id'
end

class Connection < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :likes
    has_many :users, through: likes
end
```

I want to add that i am not 100% sure of this as i am currently learning Rails myself. But this is what I came up with and hopefully its useful (and correct).

Comment: Awesome - this is great!  One thing I added was `optional: true` for the connection association so that the like can save without it needing to be set.